# How do I get email analytics in sendgrid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sendgrid, email-analytics

I am sending email using  sendgrid.

Are there any options in sendgrid to get email analytics (open/bounced/replied emails) for each users email address?

Answer (score 3):

I've done this two ways before:

1) Use [SendGrid's Event API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) to collect and aggregate the data yourself.

2) Use a service like [sendwithus](https://www.sendwithus.com/) on top of your SendGrid account, which will collect your SendGrid analytics for you and provide analytics by recipient, template, segment, etc. They also provide an [API and Ruby client](https://www.sendwithus.com/docs/api).

Comment: How to call sendrgid event api and get statistics in Rails. If you have any example then share with us. Helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're logged into SendGrid, navigate to the [Stats Dashboard](https://sendgrid.com/statistics/email).

You should then be able to see something like this:

[image: SendGrid Stats]

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes i am getting this in SendGrid website, my query is any api or gem in ruby  to get that data in my local application

Comment: You never mentioned anything about an API or Gem in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are option available for this, to get the status of individual emails sent via sendgrid.

Send a unique arguments with every email you sent and then later on you can get status of these emails with reference to unique argument.

Some more explanation of your question will help us a-lot to describe you the best possible solution.

i have recently done this work, so if you explain the whole scenario, i will come up with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get hold of this data:

Use the [SendGrid Event Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) to get near realtime information about every event for every email you send via SendGrid. It works by issuing a POST request to a URL that you specify.

You can then store all this data for consumption later on and it's by far the most granular information you can get. Key/Value stores like Redis are a good option for this, but if you want a simple option to get going, check out the [SendGrid EventKit](https://sendgrid.com/docs/VidGrid/Event_Notification/eventkit.html) to get up and running quickly.

Or:

Grab the data via the [Stats API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Stats/global.html). This endpoint allows you to grab the numbers you need in a multitude of ways for both main and subuser accounts.

Based on your question, you should investigate the Event Webhook as it will give you most clarity on what happens with *each* email you send.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [Thinbox](https://www.thinboxapp.com) to get analytics from Sendgrid, Mailgun, Mandrill, or just by bcc'ing an email address they give you. It's basically like EventKit but for the rest of the ESPs too.